# How to use ClassLoader.getResources() in jar file

Tags: java, jar, classloader

Problem statement: 
I have a jar file with a set of configuration files in a package `mycompany/configuration/file/`.
I don't know the file names.
My intention is to load the file names at runtime from the jar file in which they are packaged and then use it in my application.
As far as I understood:
 When I use the `ClassLoader.getResources("mycompany/configuration/file/")` I should be getting all the configuration files as URLs.
However, this is what is happening:
I get one URL object with URL like `jar:file:/C:/myJarName.jar!mycompany/configuration/file/`
Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: *"I don't know the file names."*  Why not?  Who put them in there? How did they put them in there (e.g. Ant, Maven etc)?

Comment: @ Andrew: As part of the build process, these files are generated and are packaged in the jar file by ANT.

Comment: Generate a list using Ant and include it in a known location in one of the Jars.  Read the list at run-time.

Comment: That is what I am doing now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what you are trying to do I don't think it is possible.

`getResource` and `getResources` are about finding named resources within the classloader's classpath, not listing values beneath a directory or folder.

So for example `ClassLoader.getResources("mycompany/configuration/file/Config.cfg")` would return all the files named **Config.cfg** that existed in the **mycompany/configuration/file** path within the class loader's class path (I find this especially useful for loading version information personally).

In your case I think you might almost have half a solution.  The URL you are getting back contains the source jar file (jar:file:/C:/myJarName.jar).  You could use this information to crack open the jar file a read a listing of the entries, filtering those entries whose name starts with "mycompany/configuration/file/".

From there, you could then fall back on the `getResource` method to load a reference to each one (now that you have the name and path)

Comment: So every `ClassLoader` has its own CLASSPATH?

Comment: @mhrsalehi From memory, yes, they can, but they might inherit the parent class loaders class path as well