# What is good practice for storing files for use in a Java project, and how do I access them?

Tags: java, file, persistence, project, javafx-2

At the moment I have a bit of a makeshift way of accessing my FXML files and CSS files which my Java code calls.

For accessing my CSS files, I have them in my `bin` folder, and access it via a reference in my FXML file as follows.

`<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane"  prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" stylesheets="splashStyle.css">`

For accessing my FXML files, I have them stored wherever my `.class` files are and access them as follows.

`FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("splashLayout.fxml"));`

So I'm curious there is a better way to do this, in terms of storing and accessing, as just now it seems very inconsistent and unprofessional.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best practice is to store resources in a folder like: src/main/resources as maven project layout recommends( see: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

For accessing them see this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/resources.html

or this: [How to use ClassLoader.getResources() in jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516655/how-to-use-classloader-getresources-in-jar-file)