# JAR - Listing files into a folder

Tags: java, jar, directory-listing

I would like to get a list of file contained in a directory which is in a jar package. 
I have an "images" folder, within it I have an `Images` class that should load all images from that directory.

In the past i used the `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("filename");` to read files, but how do I read a directory?

This is what I tried:

```
System.out.println(Images.class.getResource("").getPath());
System.out.println(new File(Images.class.getResource("").getPath()).listFiles());
```

I tried with `Images.class.getResource` because I have to work with `File` and there isn't a constructor that accepts an `InputStream`.

The code produces

```
file:/home/k55/Java/MyApp/dist/Package.jar!/MyApp/images/
null
```

So it is finding the folder which I want to  list files from, but it is not able to list files.

I've read on other forums that in fact you can't use this method for folders in a jar archive, so how can I accomplish this?

Update: if possible, i would like to read files without having to use the `ZipInputStream`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516655/how-to-use-classloader-getresources-in-jar-file

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that easily.

What you need to do:

1. Get the path of the jar file.
   Images.class.getResource("/something/that/exists").getPath()
2. Strip "!/something/that/exists".
3. Use [Zip File System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) to browse the Jar file.
   It's a little bit of hacking.

Comment: Unfortunately, `Images.class.getResource("/").getPath()` fires a `NullPointerException`

Comment: @BackSlash No, there isn't. Either `ZipFileSystem` or 'ZipInputStream` with manual filtering of entries.