# java.lang.NullPointerException while getting a filepath in Java (executing through a jar file)

Tags: java, jar, nullpointerexception

I am getting an NPE at the point of getting path of a File (an sh file in assets folder). 
I have tried to read about NPE i detail from the following thread, but this actually could not solve my problem.

[What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Following is my code snippet:

```
 File absPathofBash;

   url = ClassLoader.class.getResource("assets/forbackingup.sh");
    absPathofBash = new File(url.getPath());
```

Later I'm using it in a **ProcessBuilder**, as

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(url.getPath(), param2, param3)
```

I've also tried getting the absolute path directly, like

```
absPathofBash = new File("assets/forbackingup.sh").getAbsolutePath();
```

Using the latter way, I am able to process it, but if I create a **jar** then the file cannot be found. (although the Jar contains the file within the respective folder **assets**)

I would be thankful if anyone can help me on that.

Comment: You can't use `File` to access embedded resources which are inside the `Jar` file(s), they aren't "files" in the sense that the file system sees them, they a bunch of compressed bytes inside a zip file (essentially).  In your case, if you want to execute the file, you will need to extract the file from the Jar file (you can use `Class#getResourceAsStream`) and then execute it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have packaged your code as a jar, you can not load files that are inside the jar using file path, instead they are class resources and you have to use this to load:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("assets/forbackingup.sh");
```

This way you load `assets/forbackingup.sh` as an absolute path inside your jar. you also can use `this.getClass().getResource()` but this way the path must be relative to `this` class path inside jar.

`getResource` method gives you an URL, if you want to get directly an `InputStream` you can use `getResourceAsStream`

Hope it helps!

Comment: And how can I pipe the InputStream in ProcessBuilder ?

Comment: `ProcessBuilder` is meant to create operative system processes that usually you run as commands with args list. Thus, you can not run a shell script that are inside a jar. If you want to do that, I think you have to create a temp file from the `InputStream` and then use this tmpFile to go on `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: I have already got this working, i.e., executing a shell script through a jar. Where I got stuck is, the time I tried executing this jar directly without changing the current directory in the terminal. If I **cd** to the jar's directory, and then execute this jar file, it works perfectly. But otherwise (as per my requirement) it is not able to locate my **sh file**.

Comment: I realised this was a stupid ques, read inputstream in a file, and later the filepath into the ProcessBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Since the file itself is in the `jar` file, you could try using:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileNameFromJar);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of jar file , classloader will return URL different than that of when the target file is not embedded inside jar. Refer to answer on link which should help u : 
[How to use ClassLoader.getResources() in jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516655/how-to-use-classloader-getresources-in-jar-file)

Answer (score 0):

I got it done by creating a temp file. Though it's not difficult, yet I'm posting the code patch here:

```
InputStream stream = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().
            getResourceAsStream("assets/forbackingup.sh");

        File temp = File.createTempFile("forbackingup", ".sh");



      OutputStream outputStream =   
               new FileOutputStream(temp);

      int read = 0;

      byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

      while ((read = stream.read(bytes)) != -1) {

            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            outputStream.close();

      }
```

Now, we have this **temp** file here which we can pipe to the `ProcessBuilder` like,

```
String _filePath=temp.getPath();
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(url.getPath(), param2, param3)
```

Thank you everyone for your considerations.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Path class like :

```
Path path = Paths.get("data/test-write.txt");
if(!Files.exists(path)){
    // can handle null pointer exception
}
```

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it's not really a good answer, since it doesn't teach the OP. Instead it gives an alternative solution without explanation. This will usually lead to OP not learning, and coming back for asking a new question when a similar problem occurs. Would you mind adding some explanation?